# Integral of odd exponents of Cos(x) is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

In a 2010 exam question I found, no solution is provided. The question is:

> Show that for all $K\in \mathbb{N} $ the integral converges:
>
> $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^{2k+1}x}{x}dx$

I want to say that for every odd power of $\cos x$, since the positivity stays the same, the integral $\int \cos^{2k+1}xdx$ is bounded, and then use Dirichlet's Criterion.

I know how to actively divide the integral into the periodic regions, show that over every period the integral is 0 and bound between the maximum and minimum in the regions.

But is there a neater way to show this?

Comment: oh *that* 2010 exam question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly compute the integral $\int_{a}^{b}\cos^nxdx$. Define $J(n) = \int\cos^nxdx$ (indefinite integral). Then you get

$$J(n) = \sin x \frac{\cos^{n-1}x}{n} + \frac{n-1}{n}J(n-2) .$$

This gives a recursion ending with $J(1) = \sin x$ or $J(0) = x$. You can conclude that $J(n)$ has the form

$$J(n) = \sin x \cdot p_{n-1}(\cos x) + a_0x$$

where $p_{n-1}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ and $a_0 = 0$ if and only if $n$ is odd. Therefore $J(2k+1)$ is bounded for all $k$ and so is

$$ \int_{1}^{b}\cos^{2k+1}xdx = J(2k+1)(b) - J(2k+1)(1) .$$

But, honestly, I am not sure whether this is neater than dividing the integral into periodic regions.

Using the dividing approach you can also directly show (without Dirichlet's criterion) that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos^{2k+1}x}{x}dx$ converges. In fact, the sequence

$$a_m = \int_{m\pi - \pi/2}^{m\pi + \pi/2}\frac{\cos^{2k+1}x}{x}dx $$

converges to $0$ and the series

$$\Sigma_{m=1}^\infty a_m$$

is alternating and therefore converges.

Comment: How did you come up with the recursive integral function?

Comment: This follows from partial integration: Set $u(x) = \sin x, v(x) = \cos^{n-1}(x)$ and compute $\int u'(x) \cdot v(x) dx$.